# How to use Sinon Spy on async function that returns Axios Response

Tags: node.js, chai, sinon

I have a nested function that I'd like to use sinon.spy on (helper.postAlbum) to extract its return values. However, when `console.log(spy.returnValues[0])` I get an undefined.

Here's a rough setup

**album.js**

```
const createAlbum = async (pictures) {
   let promiseArray = await Promise.all(pic.map => {
       return helper.postAlbum(pic, pic.catergory)
})
}

module.exports = {createAlbum}
```

**helper.js**

```
const postAlbum = async (picture, catergory) => {
   const options = {
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'value'}
};

 return axios.post('/save', { picture: picture, category:category }, options);
}
```

**test.js**

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const helper = require('./helper');

describe('album create',  ()=> {

  let spy = sinon.spy(helper, 'postAlbum');

  chai.request(app)
      .post('/create')
      .end(async (err, res) => {
        expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
        expect(spy.returnValues[0]).to.have.property('date').to.not.be.null;

})
})
```

Comment: Could you improve the “rough setup” a bit more, please? I think there is some detail missing, for example, you have `let spy = (helper, 'postAlbum');` — I’m sure there is something missing there.

Comment: Updated. The method is just a spy

Comment: Are you exporting `postAlbum` from `helper.js`?